# Is skin whitening cream also safe for my 3 year old girl?

Tags: toddler, skin-care

We went out for a family trip for days and just came back home. We underestimated the harm of the sunlight and UV so we didn't bring us with sunscreen. You can imagine that we all get 'tanned', especially my 3-year-old daughter. So my remedy is try skin whitening cream, but I am not sure if it is safe for my daughter as skin whitening products contain bleaching and other ingredients. Has any one ever used one for kids?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to parenting.SE! Unfortunately, your question was closed, as it is unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: Did you want to ask what you can do to limit sun damage after the fact? Or do you want to know whether skin whitening products in general are ok for children? Or something else? Please edit your answer, so it can be re-opened.

Comment: No @sleske, that isn't why it was closed. See the reason in the box above.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Well, I think there are multiple problems with the Q. I just wanted to give OP the benefit of doubt - there are ways to interpret that Q that would not make it a medical Q. Well, let's wait for an edit.

Comment: It also smacks of being a spam or spam seed post. The original had a very spammy link. I initially gave the OP the benefit of the doubt, but its looking less likely that was the correct approach :-)

Answer (score 7):

The skin whitening cream you linked to has no Sun Protection Factor, so no, it does not work as a sun screen and is not safe for use as one.

You have already answered your headline question, is a skin whitening cream suitable for children - it has bleaching agents in it and does not have any recommendations for use on children's skin.